# Missing figure (The...)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Something is missing! Draw it and then tell me the answer to this puzzle.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's missing? This shape:

> [image: Heptagon containing HNAKXRO]

To appreciate why, we need to notice that these 17 shapes represent:

> The **first 17 columns of the Periodic Table** (which is what would follow the '...' in the title), excluding the Lanthanides and Actinides:
>
>  [image: Periodic Table, first 17 columns emphasised]
>
>  The number of segments in each shape represents the number of elements in each column; the letters are the elements' initials.
>
>  For example, column 4 contains the four elements Titanium, Zirconium, Hafnium and Rutherfordium, so is represented by a square containing the letters T, Z, H and R, clockwise from top. Columns represented by hexagons contain 6 elements beginning with those initials.
>
>  <sup>Note there is a typo in column 3's square, which should contain an 'A' in the top-left quadrant.</sup>

We can then insert the shapes given at the bottom of the puzzle into their correct positions in the sequence (click the image to see the detail):

> [image: Completed sequence]

Now to interpret the red squares at the bottom of the puzzle in a second way...

> If we replace each of these with the number of the column in the Periodic Table that they represent, we get the numbers: **14 / 15 / 2 / 12 / 5 / 19** (where the last two numbers, 1 and 9, are concatenated together).
>
>  Using A1Z26, this corresponds to **NOBLES**, which points us towards noticing that the eighteenth column is missing - the **Noble Gases** (Helium, Neon, Argon, Krypton, Xenon, Radon and Oganesson), which should be represented by a heptagon containing H, N, A, K, X, R and O, as depicted at the top of this answer.

Comment: Everything looks good. Well done!